# SQL Server logical issue in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, date-range

I have a year master with values 2019 to 2023. For each year I have created range as for 2019 to 2019, 2019 to 2020, 2019 to 2021, 2019 to 2022, 2019 to 2023. Because I want to add each year `NetValue` to next year based on projects `enddate`.

1. I want to `SUM()` on `NetValue` of each project as if any project starts in 2019 and ends in 2019 then should add in that year only.
2. if project starts in 2019 but ended in 2022 then it's net value should include in 2019, 2021 & 2022.
3. If project starts in 2019 and having `enddate` null then it means it is continued till max year value. Then it's Net Value should add in 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023.

Kindly provide some ideas to implement this logic. So far what I have tried is below:

```
;WITH YearRanges AS 
(
    SELECT 2019 AS StartYear, 2019 AS EndYear
    UNION ALL
    SELECT StartYear, EndYear + 1
    FROM YearRanges
    WHERE EndYear + 1 <= 2023
)
SELECT
    YR.EndYear AS Year,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN YEAR(T.projectstartdate) = YR.EndYear THEN cast(T.NetValue as decimal(18,2))
        WHEN YEAR(T.enddate) >= YR.EndYear THEN cast(T.NetValue as decimal(18,2))
        ELSE 0
    END) AS TotalAmount
FROM 
    YearRanges YR
JOIN 
    TrackerMainEntry T ON YEAR(T.projectstartdate) >= YR.StartYear
GROUP BY 
    YR.EndYear
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

**Tried:** I have tried to select according to the specified range.

**Resulted:** I get wrong values for each year. I have also applied `Cross Join` but still giving me wrong values.

Below is the logic that actually I have to implement

```
SELECT
    NetValue, projectstartdate, enddate 
FROM  
    [TrackerMainEntry] 
WHERE
    YEAR(projectstartdate) IN (2019) 

UNION

SELECT
    NetValue, projectstartdate, enddate 
FROM
    [TrackerMainEntry] 
WHERE
    YEAR(projectstartdate) IN (2019) 
    AND YEAR(enddate) IS NULL

UNION

SELECT
    NetValue, projectstartdate, enddate 
FROM
    [TrackerMainEntry] 
WHERE
    YEAR(projectstartdate) IN (2019) 
    AND YEAR(enddate) = 2022

UNION

SELECT
    NetValue, projectstartdate, enddate 
FROM
    [TrackerMainEntry] 
WHERE
    YEAR(projectstartdate) IN (2020)
```

Sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleData]
(
    [productname] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [NetValue] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ProjectStartDate] [date] NULL,
    [EndDate] [date] NULL);
GO

INSERT [dbo].[SampleData] ([productname], [NetValue], [ProjectStartDate], [EndDate])
VALUES ('Project_22', '-11224.68', CAST('2020-03-01' AS Date), CAST('2021-12-15' AS Date)),
       ('Project_64', '261706.4', CAST('2019-11-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-08-18' AS Date)),
       ('Project_64', '21309.44', CAST('2021-01-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-08-18' AS Date)),
       ('Project_4', '3057.2', CAST('2020-03-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_39', '88298.272', CAST('2020-07-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-08-08' AS Date)),
       ('Project_33', '256230.16', CAST('2019-12-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-08-30' AS Date)),
       ('Project_10', '219442.44', CAST('2021-10-01' AS Date), CAST('2021-11-26' AS Date)),
       ('Project_61', '-18707.8', CAST('2021-06-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_44', '40444.52', CAST('2021-10-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-09-01' AS Date)),
       ('Project_37', '989082', CAST('2021-11-01' AS Date), CAST('2021-12-15' AS Date)),
       ('Project_62', '113845.344', CAST('2019-01-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_63', '143278.56', CAST('2021-05-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-09-15' AS Date)),
       ('Project_68', '33998.896', CAST('2021-05-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-08-01' AS Date)),
       ('Project_65', '56889.04', CAST('2020-04-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_56', '279507.92', CAST('2020-10-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_20', '145405.92', CAST('2022-05-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-05-27' AS Date)),
       ('Project_60', '365556.16', CAST('2022-08-22' AS Date), CAST('2022-05-27' AS Date)),
       ('Project_5', '5322.264', CAST('2020-08-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-09-01' AS Date)),
       ('Project_51', '31690.9', CAST('2020-12-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_67', '28117.984', CAST('2021-06-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_59', '10735.488', CAST('2021-03-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_12', '2974.98', CAST('2022-05-03' AS Date), CAST('2022-05-13' AS Date)),
       ('Project_29', '18307.36', CAST('2019-09-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_47', '147818.38', CAST('2020-09-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_2', '-8660.24', CAST('2021-01-01' AS Date), CAST('2021-12-15' AS Date)),
       ('Project_16', '14490.552', CAST('2020-10-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_45', '188519.088', CAST('2021-03-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_15', '161817.76', CAST('2021-02-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-09-01' AS Date)),
       ('Project_55', '39743.344', CAST('2022-01-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-05-30' AS Date)),
       ('Project_35', '139378.08', CAST('2020-12-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-08-18' AS Date)),
       ('Project_40', '12552.72', CAST('2021-01-01' AS Date), CAST('2023-10-02' AS Date)),
       ('Project_43', '9998.896', CAST('2021-07-01' AS Date), CAST('2023-10-02' AS Date)),
       ('Project_53', '94926.32', CAST('2022-08-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-01-10' AS Date)),
       ('Project_7', '35094.992', CAST('2021-03-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_50', '20534.18', CAST('2021-05-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-09-01' AS Date)),
       ('Project_8', '674.5', CAST('2020-07-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_3', '4380.568', CAST('2019-11-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_10', '42712.64', CAST('2022-09-22' AS Date), CAST('2023-10-02' AS Date)),
       ('Project_33', '129340.44', CAST('2020-10-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_33', '119190.2', CAST('2021-01-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_33', '102820.46', CAST('2021-10-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_33', '150575.48', CAST('2022-09-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_23', '55964.16', CAST('2020-06-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_21', '-16.32', CAST('2020-08-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_6', '-544.66', CAST('2021-02-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_31', '-411', CAST('2020-08-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_42', '-378.41', CAST('2021-03-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_19', '-9460.23', CAST('2020-12-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_1', '71573.1', CAST('2021-03-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_26', '282114.4', CAST('2020-12-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_63', '19964.16', CAST('2022-08-22' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_37', '986980', CAST('2022-05-22' AS Date), CAST('2022-09-15' AS Date)),
       ('Project_57', '1349', CAST('2021-07-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_41', '998.896', CAST('2021-06-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_17', '12489.04', CAST('2022-08-22' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_53', '16853.2', CAST('2022-08-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-10-07' AS Date)),
       ('Project_20', '21003.184', CAST('2022-11-01' AS Date), CAST('2023-02-03' AS Date)),
       ('Project_37', '15302.56', CAST('2022-10-01' AS Date), NULL),
       ('Project_28', '60000', CAST('2023-01-01' AS Date), CAST('2022-10-07' AS Date)),
       ('Project_15', '108967.68', CAST('2022-12-01' AS Date), CAST('2023-02-01' AS Date));
GO
```

Comment: *Consumable* sample data, and expected results, will help us help you.

Comment: @ThomA I am editing my question to paste sample data, the data is not viewable in proper format. Do I have to upload file or just paste it ?

Comment: Ideally, provide DDL and DML statements for your sample data. Otherwise use Markdown tables.

Comment: You forgot to add the expected results as well.

Comment: @ThomA I have added sample data

Comment: I could be wrong but the basis of this seems to be the classic gaps and islands problem.  I'd suggest searching for that.  It should at least give you a good start.

Comment: Wouldn't that be generating inflated numbers, because your whole project value can be applied to multiple years? Or is this some sort of Enron bookkeeping? In which case, it's correct

Comment: @siggemannen well my manager wants the result in this way only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? (Note: I modified your CTE a little...)

```sql
;WITH YearRanges AS
(
    SELECT 2019 AS [PeriodYear]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [PeriodYear] + 1
    FROM YearRanges
    WHERE [PeriodYear] + 1 <= 2023
)

SELECT 
    yr.[PeriodYear],
    SUM(sd.NetValue) AS TotalAmount
FROM YearRanges yr
INNER JOIN dbo.SampleData sd
    ON YEAR(sd.ProjectStartDate) <= yr.[PeriodYear]
    AND 
    (
        YEAR(sd.EndDate) IS NULL
        OR YEAR(sd.EndDate) >= yr.[PeriodYear]
    )
GROUP BY yr.[PeriodYear]
ORDER BY yr.[PeriodYear]

/*

Results
-------
PeriodYear  TotalAmount
2019    654469.83
2020    1867903.70
2021    4050471.22
2022    4885286.36
2023    2060527.91

*/
```

Comment: As per I have received instructions regarding `NetValue` is it will never decrease as years goes on, but the output it is showing is decreasing the `TotalAmount` in the year of 2023

Comment: understood the projects in 2023 is less as compared with years